# How to set up 301 redirect of specific pages after moving Magento Community to new domain

Tags: magento, redirect

I moved my site domain from mysite.me to mysite.com. There are links on the web from other peoples' pages (e.g., blogger) to specific product pages on my old domain (e.g., mysite.me/cat1/prod1).

When I set up the URL Rewrite in Magento Community how do I point a specific URL from my old domain (mysite.me/cat1/prod1) to my new domain (mysite.com/cat1/prod1)?

I'm trying a Custom rewrite. I know the Target Path is relative. Is the Request Path relative too? If request path is relative than I can't do what I want.

I currently have a general 301 redirect for anything going to mysite.me to go to mysite.com. I'm assuming that I need to disable this 301 redirect at the domain level for any URL rewrite to work. However the first question to answer is if I can use URL rewrite for redirecting from one domain to another. I haven't seen a clear answer for this in my research. Just that the Target Path is relative, which makes sense, but nothing redirecting from one domain to another.

Thanks.